# Link URL that includes JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

My scenario will involve imgur: In imgur you can link to comments but the display style on the comment chains are all set to display and sometimes the threads expand incredibly large with different branches that aren't relevant to what I want to link to somebody.

My question is: Is it possible to link a comment like this

[image]

...and also to have some JavaScript activate that will hide all the child comments?

Usually you just click on the comment or the symbol to the left of it to collapse it but I'm just wondering if there's a way to link so they automatically collapse for the person who receives my link.

Please don't try to find a solution to my scenario. I just need to know how to do something like:

```
www.myurl.com/awebpage[javascriptcodethatwillrun]
```

EDIT:

Seeing as this isn't possible I am now wondering if this would be possible:

JavaScript in the URL bar:

1. using window.location.href to set the url
2. run some javascript that will edit the page locally after it loads

   javascript:window.location.href=www.myurl.com/webpage;[code for after page loads]

Comment: This question is too broad. Yes it is possible, but someone would need to write a lot of JavaScript to answer it.

Comment: @MildFuzz I sorry I may have worded it wrongly - I don't need a solution to the scenario I just need to know how to include JS along with a URL like www.myurl.com/[javascriptcodehere]. I can do the code to locate the comments and change their style myself.

Comment: you can't do that. Why would you want to?

Comment: I was just interested as I said. I thought it would be nice to be able to link websites that were then locally edited.

Comment: @MildFuzz I've changed my question but what I was wondering is if I could link a stackoverflow page and have the background changed to red (for example).

Comment: please edit your question,that's not Intelligible.

Comment: @omid I've changed the image now to give a better understanding. What else did you want updated?

Comment: you want pass code between pages and execute code passed from previous page in target page? what your server-side programing language?

Comment: @omid No this is is a hobby-like interest. No server-side. All local JS that runs after any web page is loaded. I'm just wondering if there was a way to run JS alongside a URL in one action (like a single link) but if it isn't possible that's fine. It's not like this has any relation to a job or a task that I need done.

Comment: it is possible,you need to parse `url` with javascript and split `window.location.href` for find code and execute.

Comment: @omid I would start one website1 and I want to click a link that contains javascript I would need split that up and use it to send me to that page. Would the array that now contains the URL and the javascript code come with me to website2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand what you want. You want to be able to automatically run JavaScript on a third party site?

This you can not do. One the browser goes to the next page, you can not execute any of your code. Even if you execute the url via JS, your browser will still leave your code, and start executing the code on imgur.

Comment: This is right for my initial question so i've ticked it. If you have any idea if the second is possible or not that would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Am I missing something or are you asking the same thing twice?

Comment: in the URL bar you can enter JavaScript code. I have bookmarks that cut URLs into a different format then go to them. (Like replacing YouTube with ReplayYoutube). In my second question I was wondering if I could do this exact same method but also bring some code along and edit the page that loads.

Comment: Sorry I'll try explain better: If i'm on youtube.com/video=9266942640 (not a legitimate yt url but this is an example) I want it to replay (i use it for songs) I press my bookmark that has the code to split youtube out, replace it replayyoutube, then go to the resulting url which would be something like replayyoutube.com/video=9266942640. Once the new page loads I'm unsure if any code from my bookmark will execute or be lost and not run. Any idea? e.g. replace yt with replayyt load the replayyt page then change the background color to red.